# Double integral involving Bessel functions

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I have the integral:

$$ \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \int_0^\infty f(m)J_0(mr)\,\text{d}m \,\text{d}r \tag{1}\label{1}$$

where $f(m)$ is a known but complex function, not integrable in closed form, but still continuous and non-increasing in $(0, \infty)$ interval. I need to evaluate this integral numerically, frequently. My current approach is using the Hankel transform like this:

$$ \mathcal{H}_0(r) = \int_0^\infty \frac{f(m)}{m}mJ_0(mr) \, \text{d}m, \tag{2} \label{2}$$
and then:
$$ \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \mathcal{H}_0(r) \, \text{d}r. \tag{3}\label{3}$$
Both $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{3}$ can be evaluated numerically with proper quadrature rules, however this needs the Hankel tranform to be performed many times which becomes very inefficient. Thus my question is: can i represent integral \eqref{1} in other form, which could be more efficient, possibly not involving frequent computation of Hankel transform?

**Update**:
$f(m)$ is the rational function like this example:

$$ f(m) = - \frac{0.2525 \left(0.2302 m^{3} e^{6 m} - 0.3568 m^{2} e^{8 m} + 0.3568 m^{2} e^{4 m} + 0.4918 m e^{10 m} + 1.0 m e^{6 m} + 0.0216 m e^{2 m} - 0.7623 e^{12 m} - 0.0243 e^{8 m} + 0.1021 e^{4 m} + 0.0335\right)}{0.0581 m^{4} e^{6 m} + 0.1242 m^{2} e^{10 m} + 0.0901 m^{2} e^{8 m} + 1.0 m^{2} e^{6 m} + 0.0901 m^{2} e^{4 m} + 0.0055 m^{2} e^{2 m} + 0.1925 e^{12 m} + 0.1584 e^{10 m} + 0.0472 e^{8 m} + 0.1225 e^{6 m} + 0.0276 e^{4 m} + 0.007 e^{2 m} + 0.0085} $$

Regards, Marek.

Comment: I think perhaps transforming the inner ($m$) integral as $\int_0^1 f\left(\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\right)J_0\left(r\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\right)\frac{\mathrm d\mu}{(1-\mu)^2}$
Might give faster results. Although I think knowing some more properties about $f$ could help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not see the advantages of this transform, or maybe i do not know how to approach this integral numerically... BTW. I added the example of $f(m)$.

Comment: @mrkwjc Your original integral is from $0$ to $\infty$. Usually numerical integration methods require you to be on a finite interval. What the previous commentator was suggesting is to use a substitution (not a transform) to convert your integral problem into one where the limits of integration are now from $0$ to $1$. This way the numerical integration techniques will work better.

Comment: I understand this, but this integral still involves Bessel function with argument varying from 0 to $\infty$. I think this still must involve similar integration techniques as the Hankel transform does.

Comment: See [numerical evaluation of the Hankel Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Numerical_evaluation). There is a certain change of variables that leads to a connection with the FFT. Alternatively you could use the asymptotic expression for $J_0$ as a damped cosine wave.

Comment: Currently i use approach described [here](https://ems.press/journals/prims/articles/2319) and implemented [here](https://hankel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Did not try other methods, but I believe the efficiency must be comparable. However: can the original double integral be evaluated without frequent use of this transform?